# Flutter Navigation parameters do not update on change?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-provider

My top level widget displays a list of games one can enter. When someone clicks a game they get taken via

```dart
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => EditRosterPage(roster: roster),
    ),
}
```

to a roster widget that will help them pick their team. A user will try to edit the roster and the widget in turn asks a `ChangeNotifierProvider` from the `Provider` library to update its state. The `provider` will then notifiy my top level widget that the roster has changed. It updates successfully and receives the updated roster -- but that same updated roster is not passed down through the `MaterialPageRoute` and the user cannot see that they've updated anything.

Is this expected behavior for properties passed down through Navigation to only be passed once or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you found an answer for this one yet? I assume this is quite a common pattern but surprising there seems to be no clear solution. However, given your structure where flutter provider is already in use - I would  suggest that you pass only the index from the listItem onTap's navigator push. Which then you retrieve from provider the selected item. For me, I am using a StreamBuilder with asynchronous snapshots without the local state being stored so not actually possible to find a solution :(

Comment: Yes, for my projects that still rely on Provider I instead pass down only id's of items rather than the items and I fetch them again using Provider. Providers do not extend beyond their navigation trees and so the behavior is expected. Yes, it also surprised me how little this issue was run into but the solution, although a little verbose, does work